# Open Source administration web framework

Tags: open-source, web, rest

I am developing a web server that will expose multiple data with a REST API. Mostly GET calls will be made on it, and few POSTs with data.

It's kind of an administration tool, and thus I need a Web UI. So, I need a web framework for administrative tool that can make REST calls and easily displays JSON (most of this data are text, list, no graph or pdf files or anything too complex).

I don't want to go as far as making a full Angular Website from scratch. I don't have much time, and I'm not really into making full HTML/CSS pages (even though I can do some). But I'm not sure a CMS is a good way to go, I've never used any. I'd like something in between.

I've thought of something like Grafana: choose a datasource (here a REST url) and some kind of "model/template" to display the data, with minimum configuration (but most importantly, minimum/no HTML&CSS manipulations). However, Grafana is mostly for metrics, so I can't use it as is (or maybe there is a module ?).

It also needs to be "on-premise" (no cloud-based solution) and Open Source. I'll have to put it on a docker and it will be internal.

I might be missing something like: does this even have a name ? "web admin webpage" or something ?